# How do I add pairs of elements between lists to map in scala?

Tags: list, scala

Sorry for my bad english. I don't know if the title makes sense.

Anyway, what I want to do is this.

I have `val strlist=List[String]` and val `intlist=List[Int]` also, I have a map `var env=Map[String, Int]`. Length of `strlist` and `intlist` is same. Then I want to add elements `strlist(0)->intlist(0)`, `strlist(1)->intlist(1)`, ... and so far to `env`.

How do I do this?

Comment: As I always say, the [**scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/) is your friend. `val env = (strList lazyZip intList).toMap`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez there is reason to use `lazyZip` instead of `zip`? As I think, `zip` is shorter (& more efficient) in case of one operation, compare to `lazyZip` if efficient for chained zip operation (like `xs.lazyZip(ys).lazyZip(zs)`)

Comment: @MikhailIonkin to avoid the intermediate collection.